# How to print a text with an emoji together using Python in replit.com and I don't know why I am getting this error

Tags: python, windows, performance, error-handling, compiler-errors

[This is what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZTLb.png)
[This is my try on it. I don't know why there is an error. I don't know how to print a text with an emoji.]

```
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Blv4.png)
print("""
R1cHL3
December 30th 2022
I am signing up for Replit's 100 days of Python 
challenge!
I will make sure to spend some time every day coding
along, for a minimum of 10 minute a day.
I'll be using Replit, an amazing online IDE so I can do 
this from my phone wherever I happen to be. No excuses
for not coding from the middle of a field!
"")
print("I am feeling") 
print(u'\U0001f604')
print("You can follow my progress at") --- Line 14

File "main.py", line 15
    print("You can follow my progress at")
                                     ^
SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal
```

Thank you.

I am trying different ways to expect it to work. Trying and trying until it will hopefully work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print("""
...
...
this from my phone wherever I happen to be. No excuses
for not coding from the middle of a field!
"")
```

This is the problem.  There should be three quotes on that last line, not two.